# VLC media player is not displaying video, but audio works

Tags: vlc

I had installed VLC media player from the Ubuntu Software Center recently. It worked for some time, but then instead of the video, only a blank screen was displayed with the audio. Even the same videos that could be played before did not work.

I tried uninstalling and re-installing, and I upgraded it to the latest.

I've tried: menu *Tool* → *Preferences* → *Video* → enabling *Accelerated video output (Overlay)*.

Execution via the terminal also gives the same.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr).

Comment: `uncheck accelerated video output`

Answer (score 67):

1. - Go to <kbd>Tools</kbd>→<kbd>Preferences</kbd>→<kbd>Video</kbd>
   - Remove the tick for `Accelerated video output (Overlay)`
   - Try and play the movie again, you should now see output.

#### Or

2.

- Go to <kbd>Tools</kbd>→<kbd>Preferences</kbd>-><kbd>Video</kbd>
- Change `Output` to `X11 Video output`

If the above doesn't work, that particular video might have a proprietary video format that is not supported.

Reference [here](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/455508-vlc-shows-black-screen-when-playing-movie-files-solutions).

Comment: #2 worked for me, on Ubuntu 17.04. Output defaulted to `Auto`, but specifying X11 fixed it.

Comment: #2 worked for me as well, on 17.04. Weird

Comment: X11 fixed it. Shouldn't this be reported as a bug?

Comment: 2. worked for me, on Xubuntu 16.04

Comment: @LonnieBest that might be a feature that we don't have any idea about. anyway x11 worked for me,

Comment: Second option works for me with Windows 10, but in my version (VLC 3.0.4) the option is "Direct3D11 Video Output" (I assume this is the same option - works anyway while the default of "Automatic" doesn't.

Comment: FYI, in VLC 3.0.16 (in Pop OS 22.04), I found "Hardware-accelerated decoding" under Tools, Preferences, Input/Codecs, rather than Tools, Preferences, Video. (Nice answer, +1)

Answer (score 10):

My workaround is to delete the VLC config-file.
Open a terminal in `~/.config/vlc` and

```
rm vlc-qt-interface.conf
```

Weird thing, if i delete the config file with Nautilus filemanager: still no window.

Comment: This worked for me!

Comment: Worked for me too. thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Also, This happend to me, but...

navigate to:

: menu Tool → Preferences → Video

Check the output drop-down menu

and check that you have chosen the appropriate output codec, It was set to "auto" in the drop-down and needed to be selected "X11"

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and updated to vlc 2.2.7. I had the same problem after updating the update.

Go to *Tools* -> *Preferences* -> *Video* -> *Output* and select any of the first three options that end in (XCB). This resolved the issue for me.

janitor-
[image]

You can also try either of the OpenGL options and they also work.

Comment: This fixed it for me after I upgraded to 20.04 --I still need to upgrade again to 22.04. I'd like to add that as far as I can tell you should always run VLC from the command line without options. Running it from the desktop icon seems to make it accumulate settings changes until it won't work. Then deleting everything in ~/.config/vlc as suggested by JvdH is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed this problem for a couple of years now, and have noticed this pattern and work-around:

- If VLC is minimized when it's called to play a file, the video will fail: it will show as blank/black.
- If VLC is *not* minimized when it's called to play a file, the video works just fine.

**The workaround is to make sure VLC is *not* minimized when you feed it a file to play.**

How I found this out: I have a playlist file on the desktop.  I typically press the "Show Desktop" button to minimize all windows before I run that playlist file.  If VLC was already opened, it is now minimized.  If I then open the playlist file, the VLC windows will pop back up, but the video will fail.

However, if I make sure to bring VLC back to its windowed state *before* opening the playlist file, the video works.

Answer (score 1):

If the VLC still play without video the problem can be due to the incompatible video codec contained in the files. In this case, maybe need to convert the file to VLC more supported video format. You can choose Makemkv or Pavtube video converter,both powerful video tools.

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix and no u don't need to listen to the above. Go into VLC and go to bottom right where the 3 dots are located and go to settings. Then go to video settings and turn off hardware decoding. Problem solved

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 22.10 Wayland VLC 3.0.17.4. When I purged the application, it worked exactly one time. When the vlc was launched for the second time, the video remained blank, however any snapshot taken worked.

It turned out, deleting the geometry line from ~/.config/vlc/vlc-qt-interface.conf helped.
`geometry=@ByteArray(\x1\xd9\xd0\xcb\0\x3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\a\x7f\0\0\x4\x37\0\0\x2\x80\0\0\0@\0\0\a\x7f\0\0\x2\xcf\0\0\0\x1\x2\0\0\0\a\x80\0\0\0\0\0\0\0%\0\0\a\x7f\0\0\x4\x37)`

However, it got recreated every vlc launch. **I changed the screen size on the blank video** window by mouse and re-launched. It works now.

May this strange advice help some future visitors of this old issue.

Comment: I tested this on Kubuntu 22.04 with VLC 3.0.17.4 and it fixes the issue. The above suggestions didn't. Unfortunately the `geometry=...` line from the `[general]` section has to be removed before every start.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 and fresh VLC.
My video card is NVidia and I was using the binary proprietary driver version 361.42
I switched to version 340.96 of the same driver and I got the video running without any problems.

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I accidentally deleted `libavcodec` (probably it was targeted by apt-get autoremove after deleting some other package). In my case no player (I tried vlc, xplayer, smplayer) except browsers were not able to play any video (I tried for mp4, avi, mkv) but the audio worked. Re-installing this package fixed my problem. So check if it's installed.

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me, but a "mark for reinstall" in synaptic did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Kubuntu 18.10 x64) changing `Output` to `X11 Video output` (as **Ravan** proposed) did not help, but `XVideo output (XCB)` helped.

So...

- Go to <kbd>Tools</kbd>→<kbd>Preferences</kbd>-><kbd>Video</kbd>;
- Change `Output` to `XVideo output (XCB)`.

Answer (score 0):

After trying (almost) all suggested solutions above, I found a workaround to this VLC bug:
Deselect

> <kbd>Tools</kbd>→<kbd>Preferences</kbd>-><kbd>Interface</kbd>-><kbd>Appearance</kbd>-><kbd>Adjust interface to video size</kbd>

This is a solution similar to the "removing `geometry=@ByteArray...`" approach.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this too (I did it in Ubuntu 16.04.03)

uninstall VLC at all, then open terminal window and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

it works for me, so I hope you can get it too.

Answer (score -2):

Resetting preferences helped me

Tools -> Preferences -> Reset Preferences